# SIM900A network connection

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, network

I can't connect to the network.
Hardware used: **Arduino UNO** and **SIM900A GSM module**
Tutorial used: https://www.instructables.com/id/GSM-SIM900A-With-Arduino/
Sim card used: **Orange** (I set it on 2G frequency and disabled pin code)
**I am from Romania.**

Based on the tutorial above, once the connection is established successfully, the status/network LED on the SIM900A will blink continuously every 3 seconds. This does not happen to me, so it is a problem from the start. It keeps on searching for a network to connect.

Would you mind helping me, please?

Thank you so much!